# Mouseenter Keeps Firing Because of the Wiggle Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, mouseenter

This is probably an easy one for somebody. I'd like this plugin code to fire one when the mouse goes over the element, wiggling the element 3 or 4 times (or whatever is specified), then stop.. however it just keeps firing

here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZKVMk/7/

I'm using this little wiggle plugin:
http://labs.wondergroup.com/demos/mini-ui/index.html

Seems the plugin just makes mouseenter stay active.

ideas:

- somehow move the call to the wiggle function outside the mouseenter so it only fires once?
- make use of the plugin's callback function to tell mouseenter it should stop?
- incorporate bind() or unbind() somehow?

many thanks!

Comment: In Chrome, your fiddle seems to work properly for me, but FF and IE8 go a little nuts.

Comment: It is not the event being fired. It is the effect of the wiggle plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when the element is moved it re-fires the MouseEnter event in Firefox and IE, so the simplest way to fix this (IMHO of course) is to just put in a variable that can be reset that prevents the wiggle method being called multiple times.

```
$(function() {
    var wiggled = false;

    $('#tata').mouseover(function() { 
        if(!wiggled) {
            $(this).wiggle({
                speed: 60,
                wiggles: 3,
                travel: 5,
            });
            //output
            var el = $('#output');
            var n = + el.text();
            el.text(++n);

            wiggled = true;
        }
    }).mouseout(function(e) {        
        wiggled = false;
    });
});
```

**Update**: I should add that I was only able to test this in FF, IE and Chrome may behave differently, but I wouldn't expect them to.

Comment: this is a beautiful thing. works great. tested on safari as well. a little logic goes a long way. here's the final fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZKVMk/17/

Answer (score 0):

try entering this as well

```
$('#tata').mouseout(function() {        
    $(this).stop();
});
```

This will stop all the animations while allowing the currently animation to finish